# Transition image in javascript between 2 points

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do an image transition in javascript between 2 points. First coordonates are the image initial x and y and second are the x and y of the "click" event. How can I simulate a transition in Javascript?

Comment: Are you using jQuery. `.animate` could simplify a lot of things

Comment: Nope, I'm trying to learn Javascript and I'm not using any libraries.

Comment: Okay :) I'll post an answer.

Comment: Use css for smooth transition effect, or else jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Your code will just move the image from one position to another in a jiffy (not like a smooth animation).

If this is what you are doing, then just make `position` of your `img` `relative`.

```
<img id="player" src = "images/volley.png" style="postion:relative"></img>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS3 transitions your JavaScript seems correct:

```
transition: all 1s ease;
```

You can change `ease` to `linear` depending on the effect you want. You can also adjust `1s` for how long it takes to move. You also need `position: relative` so `left` and `top` can actually do something

```js
var x_click;
    var y_click;
    var player = document.getElementById("player");
    document.addEventListener("click", move_player)

    function move_player(e) {
      x_click = e.clientX;
      y_click = e.clientY;

      player.style.left = x_click - player.clientWidth / 2 + "px";
      player.style.top = y_click - player.clientHeight / 2 + "px";
    }
```

```css
.animateable {
  position: relative;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<!--Some image I found-->
<img id="player" class="animateable" src="https://jardinsoli.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/person.png" />
```